# Send function from controller into my angular directive

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a directive where I send at templateUrl with it to a html where there is a button. What I would like to know is. Can i send a function from the controller where I use the directive to my directive so I can register when the button is click, and then the input call the function.

My templateUrl html pages

```
<div class'btn' ng-click='nestedinputFunction()'>Test button</div>
```

Use of my directive on my html page where my controller is

```
<nested-click input-function='myFunction'></nested-click>
```

the controller where the function is

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope' function ($scope) {
    $scope.inputFunction = function(){
    alert("Function is being called!");
}
```

}]);

My directive

```
app.directive('nestedClick', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        inputFunction: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
        return '/AngularJS/Directives/nestedClick.html'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.nestedinputFunction = scope.inputFunction
    },
}
```

});

Do anyone know if this is possible, and if, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the '&' binding.

```
app.directive('nestedClick', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            nestedinputFunction: '&inputFunction',
        },
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return '/AngularJS/Directives/nestedClick.html'
        }
    }
});



<nested-click input-function='myFunction()'></nested-click>
```

Here's an easy explanation of the '&' binding: https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am

Comment: Awsome, gonna try it out, i will report back when im done. thanks

Comment: it worked. Thanks man, Lets say that the function in my main controller wanted a input value, can i take this out in the directive?

Comment: Sure, take a look at the link in the answer. It shows exactly that.

Comment: hmm. just looked at it again, still can't see it anywhere, i can see how he takes it and send the function to his templateUrl, but can't find where he takes the input value of the function and manipulates it in he's js directive logik.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. By 'input value' do you mean a parameter? Can you give an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: yes, i talking about Parameter. If we use the code from my qustion. and change the using of the directive to look like this `<nested-click input-function='myFunction(22)'></nested-click>` where the 22 is the parameter

Comment: You can't do it. You need to add another binding to the directive scope using '=' for the extra input, and then use something like `<nested-click input-function='myFunction()' other-value='someControllerScopeParam'></nested-click>`

Comment: Ohh i see. damn, was trying to "Extend" the Ng-Click directive so i should do a extre tag curse i was gonna use it everwhere. Anywhy, you answer was the rigth one, once again. thanks!